# WSL2 Ubuntu 18.04 - Really strange performance

Tags: python, performance, pip

I have an apparently clean installation of WSL2, and I'm using a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, just starting everything on the new WSL2.

Problem:
I'm used to making use of pip for python package installation. But here, it's extremely slow. Sometimes it takes so much time trying to connect with the server to download the package, that it returns a "timeout error". Sometimes it works, but after a huge amount of time (I'm talking about 20min to download Pandas...).

Also, there is this message at the start of any installation:

> pip install pandas
>
> WARNING: The directory '/home/lsmliborio/.cache/pip' or its parent
> directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The
> cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that
> directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

I've tried the `-H` argument, and the message goes away, but the huge time is the same.

Another message I get at the start is this:

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable